# I am trying to plot geom_bar onto ggplot, but geom_bar has a differing sample source and R pops out an error

Tags: r

I wanted to plot geom_bar onto ggplot that represents the mean of the data. I took data for ggplot that is smaller in size in order to not overwhelm the plot, but wanted to use bigger data for bar plot, unfortunately it doesn't allow me to, because it says that: `Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2)` It's weird because it seems like it shouts an error "aes(x = min, y = ratings)" but when I remove the geom bar everything is ok. Has anyone got any ideas?

```
ggplot(random_scores, aes(x = win, y = ratings)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_bar(data = avg_samples, stat = "identity", alpha = 0.4 )
```

Here is another try:

```
ggplot(random_scores, aes(x = win, y = ratings)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_bar(data = avg_samples, stat = "identity", alpha = 0.4, aes(x = win, y =ratings ))
```

Comment: as the error msg says, you need to provide aesthetics for geom_bar as well, as the data provided is diff. `geom_bar(data = avg_samples, aes(x = col_name),...)`

Comment: @Neel Here I posted what I tried but it gives me the same error.

Comment: mind sharing data? use dput(your_df). I understand you are trying to plot actual via geom_point and avg value via geom_bar. I guess you need not have to have additional df.

Comment: if the error is same, then it's like the `unique(avg_samples$win)` is not equal to `unique(random_scores$win)` . Check this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want to achieve. have used famous `iris` dataset. If this is what you are looking for, you know, what's next. just change df, field names.

```
iris %>% ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(Species), y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", aes(fun = "mean"), alpha = 0.5)
```

**Edit** Even the suggested approach works for me and gives the same output.

```
avg_length = iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(mean_len = mean(Petal.Length))

iris %>% ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(Species), y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_bar(data = avg_length, aes(x = Species, y = mean_len), stat = "identity", alpha = 0.4)
```

**output**

[image]